# One office plugin for both Office 2010 and 2007

Tags: .net, ms-office, plugins, vsto, backwards-compatibility

I've developed an office VSTO3 application for MS Office 2007. Now I'm in a process of porting it for Office 2010.

I've created a new project targeted for 2010 and mostly just copy-pasting the code from 2007 project. I've moved as much code as I can to external libraries but still there's quite much code in main project.

I was wondering if there's a better way of doing that? Do you know if I can have one project targeted for both platforms. I don't care for backwards compatibility for older version then 2007.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An AddIn targeting 2007 should also work in Office 2010, or you can use a 2010 AddIn in Office 2007 as long as you don't use any of the new features int 2010.

The following link gives details about [Running Solutions in Different Versions of Microsoft Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772080(VS.100).aspx)

Comment: It works but there are some problems with i.e. Outlook which in 2007 has standard main window with icons bars etc. and in 2010 has a Ribbon there so it's not that straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You should mention whether you're targeting Outlook, Excel, etc... Pretty big omission :)

Excel DNA is a platform for Excel addins that I like, which plays with 2007 and 2010.

I have developed an Outlook addin for 2007 that installs and mostly works in 2010 but has weird bugs I haven't got around to diagnosing.

So - it depends on what you want to do.